# UIButton in UITableView cell like "Delete Event"

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I'd like to add a button to a table cell. The "Delete Event" in the calendar app inspired me... (a similar case is "Share Contact" in contacts)

As of now there's

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //..yadayadayada
  cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"buttonCell"];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"buttonCell"] autorelease];
  }
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
  [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  button.titleLabel.text = @"Foo Bar";
  [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

which produces a button, indeed. It doesn't look yet how it's supposed to (it's obvious I've never dealt with buttons in iPhone, yet), but is this at least the right approach?

Comment: Will the resultant action of the button be different depending on which row it's in? (e.g. email the current contact in this row, etc...)

Comment: If it is, you can set the tag of each cell's button to say, the indexPath row, and then read the tag of the sender in the selector that gets executed on a touch.

Comment: Well, as with "Delete Event" I'll only have one button at the bottom of the UI i.e. in the last row.

Answer (score 19):

The way you have it now each time a cell is shown you're allocating a button, setting its value, and adding it to the cell's contentView. When the cell gets reused (via `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`) you'll be creating *another* new button, adding it to the cell (on top of the old one) etc. The fact that it's gone through `addSubview` but no explicit release means each button's retain count will never go to zero so they'll all stick around. After a while of scrolling up and down the cell will end up with hundreds of button subviews which probably isn't what you want.

A few tips:

- Never allocate stuff inside a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call unless it's done when `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is returning nil and you're initializing the cell. All other subsequent times you'll be handed back the cached cell that you will have already set up so all you have to do is change the labels or icons. You're going to want to move all that button allocation stuff up inside the `if` conditional right after the cell allocation code.
- The button needs to have a position and also a target set for it so it'll do something when tapped. If every cell is going to have this button a neat trick is to have them all point to the same target method but set the button's `tag` value to the `indexPath.row` of the cell (outside the cell allocation block since it varies for each cell). The common tap handler for the button would use the tag value of the sender to look up the underlying data in the dataSource list.
- Call `release` on the button after you've done an `addSubview`. That way the retain count will fall to zero and the object will actually get released when the parent is released.
- Instead of adding the button via `addSubview`, you can return it as the `accessoryView` for the cell so you don't have to worry about positioning it (unless you're already using the accessoryView for something else -- like disclosure buttons).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the valuable hints and explanations. An iPhone programming newbie like me sure appreciates that.

As for tip 4, as with "Delete Event"/"Share Contact" I'll only have one button at the bottom of the UI i.e. in the last row. So, it cannot be the accessoryView, but it has to fill the entire row. I'm still struggling with that.

Comment: Regarding #3, releasing the button will crash your application.  He isn't allocing it.

Answer (score 7):

I took a different approach to creating an equivalent to the 'Delete Event' button in the Calendar app. Rather than add a button as a subview, I added two background views (red and darker red, with nice gradients) to the cells and then rounded off the corners and set the border to grey.

The code below creates a re-usable cell (in the usual fashion). The two images referred to ('redUp.png' and 'redDown.png') were taken from a screenshot of the calendar's 'Delete Event' button. (That seemed quicker than creating the gradients programmatically.) There's scope for a bit more fine tuning to get it even closer to the Calendar's 'Delete Event' appearance, but this is pretty close.

The button's action is triggered by the tableView delegate method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method.

```
// create a button from a table row like the Calendar's 'Delete Event' button
// remember to have an #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> some above this code

static NSString *CellWithButtonIdentifier = @"CellWithButton";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellWithButtonIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellWithButtonIdentifier] autorelease];
  [[cell textLabel] setTextAlignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];

  UIImageView* upImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redUp.png"]];
  UIImageView* downImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redDown.png"]];

  [cell setBackgroundView: upImage];
  [cell setSelectedBackgroundView: downImage];

  [[upImage layer] setCornerRadius:8.0f];
  [[upImage layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
  [[upImage layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
  [[upImage layer] setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];

  [[downImage layer] setCornerRadius:8.0f];
  [[downImage layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
  [[downImage layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
  [[downImage layer] setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];

  [[cell textLabel] setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
  [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [cell  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; // needed for 3.2 (not needed for later iOS versions)
  [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0]];

  [upImage release];
  [downImage release];
 }
 return cell;
```

Comment: You should add `[cell.textLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [cell.textLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];` to the code. That gives the text a slightly embossed effect so it looks more like the native button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is generally the correct approach.

A tip:

- Set the callback for your button events, so that it actually does something when clicked.

  ```
  [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatMyButtonShouldDo:)   
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  ```

**EDIT**: Adjusted code for using a system button, which renders a lot of what I had written uneccessary.

Comment: In his example code, there is no need to release the button, because [UIButton buttonWithType:] returns an autoreleased instance.

Comment: You're exactly correct, I copied that from code *I* had where I used my initWithFrame. Adjusting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The hint with release/autorelease was noted.
Is it really necessary to fiddle with the frame? I simply want the button to fill the entire table cell (i.e not worry about position and size); "Delete Event" demonstrates this nicely.

Comment: Yeah, I made things too complicated by copying my code, where I don't use System buttons, I set the frame and the background images by hand. I abbreviated my answer considerably.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right track, that's the easiest way to add a subview to a cell (the other is subclassing a `UITableViewCell`).

Check the [Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid positioning and memory management hassles you can create a specialized cell class and link to a XIB. That sounds like the cleanest approach to me. Here is the link:
http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/