# Returning value to parent view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, protocols

I've got the following situation: I've got a UISwipeGestureRecognizer hooked up on my table cell. On swipe, two buttons get their .hidden-status switched to `NO`.

Those cells are custom made. Meaning, the IBAction of those buttons is in that controller. Now I'd like the UIButton in those custom cells to send back a variable to the parent view. That parent view is the UIViewController (containing a UITableView).

How can I do this? I've read about protocols, but I can't get a solid example for that... Or are there any other ideas? They are all welcome :)

Comment: If you have control over your view hierarchy, the `superview` property might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are following may result in a crash or a memory leak as you have to retain the controller of your uitableview cell content.

However protocols are simple approach where after you create your table view cell you can allocate the viewcontroller (which creates the table view) as a delegate to all actions for the cell's content view.

In your custom cell's controller just call the delegate method and it will be handled by your parent view.
It may sound confusing, but its really simple. Will try to post sample code.

```
@protocol yourDelegate;

@interface yourViewController{
id<yourDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<yourDelegate> delegate;
@end
@protocol yourDelegate
- (void)passThisActionToMainController;
- (void)passThisEventToMainController;
@end
```

Once you are done with the above in your table view cell view controller, in your main controller create an instance of your view controller and then

```
controller.delegate = self;
```

In your cell's view controller when a user taps or performs any action then call

```
[delegate passThisActionToMainController];
```

or

```
[delegate passThisEventToMainController];
```

This way your main controller gets the event and it can be processed.

Alternate way to do this would be to create the buttons when you create the cell and handle the events. I would recommend this approach.

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatMyButtonShouldDo:)   
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The above line is copied from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076785/uibutton-in-uitableview-cell-like-delete-event).

Comment: Thanks, and you were right. It didn't sound logical, at all, to me :) Some example code would really help, thanks for your time :D

Comment: @Praveen S: Have you got a nice example for me on using protocols? I'd like to use that, but all the examples on the internet/fora are vague to me...

Comment: @Praveen S: Hey, thanks for the update. I've gotten as far as this before, but I have absolutely no clue where the chunk of `@protocol yourDelegate; ... @end` should be, nor do I know what `controller` is in `controller.delegate = self`. I fail to see the logics in here :(

Comment: Ok, @protocol should be in your view controller from where you will pass the handling to another view controller(main controller). And controller.delegate will be in function where you create your child view controller.

Comment: That way it will pass the handling to parent from the child view controller.

Comment: @Praveen S: Sorry if I'm being a bother, but.. If I understood correctly, the @protocol-part should be in detailView.h, while the `detailcontroller.delegate = self;` should be right before `[navcontroller pushViewController:detailcontroller animated:YES];`. This doesn't work so it's obviously not correct, haha, but since I don't understand this, I don't know how to place the code...

Comment: You have got it all wrong. When you do detailcontroller.delegate = self, you have also got to implement the 2 methods in this class. In your detail controller class all you have to do is call [delegate passThisActionToMainController]. Then the action will be delegated from detailcontroller to the class where you are adding it.

Comment: @Praveen S: Thanks, I'll play around a bit with it.

Comment: @Praveen S: Sorry, but I still totally lost here. I declared the protocol in the .h of the mainView, so now I've got to create those methods somewhere.. in mainView.m, I suppose. And when I try `detailcontroller.delegate = self`, it gives a fault declaring he can't find 'delegate'.. :(

Comment: http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#protocols http://jonmsterling.com/2009/08/01/using-custom-delegates-in-objective-c.html