# How to place UIButton into the uitableview cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, uibutton

I am able to create a `tableview` with  `textlabel` and with `detaillabeltext`.

In addition to that, is it possible to add `UIButton` into the cell.

I mean after the detaillabeltext, can i place a `UIButton` ( like "Remove" button )

Currently i have the following code

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    profileName = [appDelegate.sentItemsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    NSString *subjectData = [profileName.sent_subject stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ ", subjectData];

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];


    NSString *CompanyName = [profileName.sent_content stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ ",CompanyName];

    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:249.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:2.0];

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks for you time and helps!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIButton in UITableView cell like "Delete Event"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076785/uibutton-in-uitableview-cell-like-delete-event)

Comment: For what, you want to add the button? Like if you want to implement delete functionality you can use accessory, otherwise you'll have to implement every thing as a subview of your table view cell.

Comment: @rptwsthi : not like delete functionality . i want to call my "add to favourites" button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[cell addSubview:button];
```

Comment: it is a right solution, but it will hide all prior text(label and sub label)

Comment: no it will not hide the previous ones... give the cooridates correctly

Comment: @rptwsthi: otherwise you can see this tutorial it is good http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder

Comment: from this tutorial use can add the image also in your cell http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284

Answer (score 2):

You can add button or any other control to the content view of cell.

```
UIButton *cellButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
[cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(uploadData:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[cellButton setTitle:@"Upload Now" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
cellButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 180, 150, 35);
[cell.contentview addSubview:cellButton];
[cellButton release];
```

Add any control to cell's content view